what does "modified today" mean?
The post The bike shop won't fix my newly bought bike appears at the top of my active feed.
If I click on the "modified 1 hour ago" link, it just takes me to the page.
However, I can't see anything on that page dated more recently than 2017, neither question, answers, nor comments.
At the top of the page is a "modified today" link that also just returns to itself.
What am I supposed to be seeing that has changed?


I don't know what tags to use

Your tags are fine - you can also glean a little more info by checking OP's account.  It shows their account is only about as old as that post modification, and may show you other details that help show something happened.

Users with more rep can see what has happened, you can not (yet).
Someone had posted a long story about another bike where the bike shop did/does not want to repair a bike with problems.
As it was not an answer I deleted it, in a comment I invited to post as a question if that was their intention.
This is one of the small but annoying things in the Stack Exchange sites, you get to see something must have happened but you can not find it.

For reference, there’s also another case, but only if the author is “Community”, which are cases where the SE engine decides that a post is worth promoting. In that case the reason is in the change history of the post.
The case I’m thinking about are questions that have not been answered, or if the proposed answers have not been upvoted, so the reasoning is that bumping it on the main page may attract better answers or votes.

Example: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/posts/91945/timeline

Interestingly, I found another case today where a user is displayed as modifying a question with no edits shown for either question or answers.
High-rep users with a gold star in a tag can directly edit the duplicates list of questions closed as duplicates within that tag.  The question is then bumped with the user showing as having modified it, but the question itself doesn't show the edit.
Like Renaud's case, this is visible in the question's timeline as a "duplicates list edited" event.
